# OpenCV Denoising is very slow

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Require image denoising. Try it with OpenCV and got very bad performance ~30s per image!

try to use:

```
cv::fastNlMeansDenoising
cv::fastNlMeansDenoisingColored
cv::xphoto::dctDenoising
```

images : maxsize(1024x1024) colred 3 channel

sample of calling:

```
Mat src;
cv::imread("myfileName.jpg", src); //assume it's 1024x768 photo
Mat trg(src.size(),src.type());
cv::xphoto::dctDenoising(src,trg,15); // sygma 15 got from algorithm's site as balanced value
```

All works well but VERY slow.

My configuration:

Lenovo T510, core i7

Windows 10

OpenCV 3.0.0 (sources - latest - stable)

TBB (latest bin from official site)

OpenCV built with VS2015 with default CMAKE setting without "world" module and WITH_TBB, all TBB dirs set well to (.../ia32/vc12)

(For first look i thought that problem is that my opencv built without TBB, but TBB not help with denoising)

Resources:

1. During execution CPU loaded up to 100% all cores (so multiprocessing in work)
2. Uses up to 14  threads  (so mutithreading is in work)

Is where way to fix this performance issue or it's real speed of denoising with OpenCV?

May be it's some issues with C++ settings my console app built (i'm from .net world and C++ is not so familiar for me)?

Comment: Have you tried using a smaller search window with NLMeans?

Comment: have try  by your suggestion  cv::fastNlMeansDenoising(_out, tmp,3, 3,3) - (defaul is 3,7,21) it's quick of course but noise is not reduced at all. Any time when i enlarge image page size it gain it's minimum 30s time.

Answer (score 4):

Answer was simple - i was using Debug version of opencv (how it's usual for .net) but for C++ performance vary dramatically between Debug and Release configuration.

After remapping to Release build i have duration nearby 5s per image. It's not so fast i was expected but it's usable.

Answer (score 0):

The processing is slow because it has to handle many things. But if you reduce the search window or template window size, it will be faster. However, the accuracy may not be as good as before.
One simple suggestion is to use the offline mode and save the results in a different file for later use. it works especially when you want to reduce noise from video frames.